# How to access an Object in an Object in javascript

Tags: javascript

Hi I have a "persons" Object that contains four "person" Objects

```
[Object, Object, Object, Object]
```

In turn, each these "person" Objects contain keys and values.  How do I access these values in Javascript?  Trying this to access their "name" field, for example, doesn't work:

```
for(var person in data.persons) {

    var nameList = nameList + person.name; 
}
```

I'm a JS newbie.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since that your `persons` object is actually an `Array`, you can access it with a simple `for`, but iterating with an index variable, like this:

```
var nameList = '';
for (var i=0, person; person = data.persons[i]; i++) {
    nameList += person.name;
}
```

or eventually, like this:

```
var nameList = '';
for (var i=0; i < data.persons.length; i++) {
    nameList += data.persons[i].name;
}
```

---

What you're doing there is to iterate over the indexes, so your `person` variable holds an index number, not a person object:

```
for(var person in data.persons) {
    // person will be 0, 1, 2, 3...
    // by the way you can still do:
    nameList += data.persons[person].name;
}
```

Comment: that is going to give you an index out of bounds exception as you never check the length of the array.

Comment: @bhspencer: No, since Javascript doesn't throw out of bounds exceptions. It will just give `undefined` when it gets to the end.
The problem with this approach is if there is a falsy value partway through the array, it will stop and not continue past it. Using the length is much better.

Comment: @bhspencer Nope, when the for loop reaches an undefined value it stops because the second boolean (yes it's boolean) condition is not met.

Comment: ok my mistake, but surely this isn't considered good practice to rely on an undefined to terminate a loop.

Comment: @bhspencer it's still valid in this case, since that the Array holds Objects.

Comment: I don't doubt that it will work. Just don't think it is a good idea.

Comment: Why u choose all methods with index? U really hate .each?

Comment: @Legendary `forEach` (not `each`) is not guaranteed to be supported by all the browsers and JS engines.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli do you really worry about IE below 8? 30.03.2015

Comment: @Legendary I don't, and I actually exclude IE in most of my browsers, but I don't know where the OP wants his code to work... so I'm giving the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use a for-in loop with an array. Use a for loop instead with a counter.

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.persons.length; i++) {
    var person = data.persons[i];
    var nameList = nameList + person.name; 
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that it's not a good idea to declare variables inside a `for` loop, this can lead to nasty bugs when combined with closures and variable hoisting.

Answer (score 1):

Mb it because of your syntax ? Try that and show your output:

```
var nameList = '';
var test = {name: 'Joe'};
var persons = [test, test];
persons.forEach(function(v, i){
  console.log(v.name);
  console.log("index = " + i);
  nameList = nameList + v.name; 
});
console.log(nameList);
```

P.s edit and check, all ok!